# how to do sorting in ng-repeat in angularjs? :<li class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6" ng-repeat="item in eventsFromCatalogData | orderBy : item.id">

Tags: json, angularjs

But this is not working
 here eventsFromCatalogData  is an JSON array 
and item.id is coming as numbers

this is my json array

```
    [ {
        "id" : 3,
        "eventTypeDef" : "2",
        "catalog" : "145",
        "user" : "1",
        "name" : "event name postmasdsdsn",
        "status" : "NEW",
        "description" : "description test",
        "invTotal" : 10,
        "regStartTs" : "11-24-2014 10:10:25",
        "regEndTs" : "12-22-2014 10:10:35",
        "publishDate" : "12-22-2014",
        "imgUrl" : "testUrl"
    }, {
        "id" : 297,
        "eventTypeDef" : "2",
        "catalog" : "145",
        "user" : "1",
        "name" : "JPZSfrom test",
        "status" : "NEW",
        "description" : "Test DEscription",
        "invTotal" : 10,
        "regStartTs" : "11-24-2014 00:00:00",
        "regEndTs" : "11-24-2014 00:00:00",
        "publishDate" : "11-24-2014"
    } ]
```

I gave code like this

But its not sorting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **orderBy** property, use it on property by which you want to sort.

```
<div ng-repeat="object in objects | orderBy:name">
 <span>{{object.name}}</span>
</div>
```

[Tutorial for reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Comment: <ul ng-show="layout == 'grid'" class="grid row">
        <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6" ng-repeat="item in eventsFromCatalogData | orderBy : id ">

            {{item.id}}</li></ul> But am not getting sorted?

Answer (score 1):

To sort by a particular property, you need to specify that property's name as a *string* in the `orderBy` filter:

```
<li class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"
    ng-repeat="item in eventsFromCatalogData | orderBy:'id'">
```

[Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy):

> expression - A predicate to be used by the comparator to determine the order of elements.
>
> Can be one of:
>
> - function: Getter function. The result of this function will be sorted using the <, =, > operator.
> - **string: An Angular expression. The result of this expression is used to compare elements (for example name to sort by a property called name or name.substr(0, 3) to sort by 3 first characters of a property called name). The result of a constant expression is interpreted as a property name to be used in comparisons (for example "special name" to sort object by the value of their special name property). An expression can be optionally prefixed with + or - to control ascending or descending sort order (for example, +name or -name). If no property is provided, (e.g. '+') then the array element itself is used to compare where sorting.**
> - Array: An array of function or string predicates. The first predicate in the array is used for sorting, but when two items are equivalent, the next predicate is used.
>
> If the predicate is missing or empty then it defaults to '+'.

Comment: <ul ng-show="layout == 'grid'" class="grid row">
        <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6" ng-repeat="item in eventsFromCatalogData | orderBy:'id'">

            {{item.id}}    <l/i></ul> bit its not sorting ? :(

Comment: @midhunk What happens if you correct the typo in `<l/i>`?

Comment: is it possible to get from descending to ascending order

Comment: @midhunk To sort in descending order, you would use `'-id'`.

Comment: rite now am getting ascending to descending order,but can i get from descending to ascending order??

Comment: @midhunk why don't you read the documentation? It's all explained there. Quote: `{{ orderBy_expression | orderBy : expression : reverse}}. reverse: (optional) boolean: Reverse the order of the array.`

Comment: @midhunk I don't know what "ascending to descending means". Do you want the values to be increasing, or decreasing?

Comment: @JLRishe: i got it  :)

Comment: @midhunk and why did you accept the incorrect answer?

Comment: @midhunk Any reason you accepted the incorrect answer yet again?

Comment: @midhunk What does that mean?